# Best way to index with these repeated queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I'm trying to experiment with indexes but I'm still new to it. Let's say I use the following queries a lot so I need to make indexes for the tables `music` and `musicians`.

```
    SELECT *
    FROM music
    where musician_id = @id

    SELECT *
    FROM music
    where musician_id = @id and date_of_birth > @date

    SELECT *
    FROM music
    where date_of_birth > @date1 and date_of_birth < @date2

    SELECT first_name, last_name, musician_website
    FROM musicians
    where last_name = @last_name

    SELECT customer_id, first_name, last_name,musician_website
    FROM musicians
    where last_name = @last_name and musician_website= @site
```

What do you think is the best solution if I want to make indexes for these queries. Is it best to make one for each column that I want (for example 1 for `musician_id`, one for `date_of_birth` etc...) or maybe take them as pairs like this: `musician_id` with `date_of_birth` ,then `last_name`  with  `musician_website` and then just `date_of_birth` for the third query (where I need them to be ordered by date).
What would be the best option to do here and why?

Comment: at least include the table schema... and why does `music` have a `date_of_birth`? Are we supposed to guess that you meant to include a join there?

Comment: no it's just a bad name for the table. table music hold info about the musician and the date of birth.

Comment: Sounds like you need to worry about [normalization](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/an-introduction-to-database-normalization/) before indexing.

Comment: Yes indeed, thankfully I am at the start of the project. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The indexes you want are:

- `music(musician_id, date_of_birth)` (queries 1 and 2)
- `music(date_of_birth)` (query 3)
- `musicians(last_name, web_site)` (queries 4 and 5)

For the last index, you can include `customer_id` and `first_name`, if you really want.

Comment: queries 1 , 2 and 3 refer to a table called `music` instead of `musicians`

Comment: @SqlZim . . . Thank you; better eyes than I.